# Error trying to use the same class/struct defined in multiple swift-package-manager targets

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I would like to give the same name to a `class` or `struct` defined in different SPM targets, but I get the following errors:

[image]
[image]

`MyModel` is defined in both `MyLibraryTargetOne` and `MyLibraryTargetTwo`

here my SPM manifest

```swift
// swift-tools-version:5.3
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
  name: "MyLibrary",
  products: [
    // Products define the executables and libraries a package produces, and make them visible to other packages.
    .library(
      name: "MyLibrary",
      targets: ["MyLibrary"]
    ),
    .library(
      name: "MyLibraryTargetOne",
      targets: ["MyLibraryTargetOne"]
    ),
    .library(
      name: "MyLibraryTargetTwo",
      targets: ["MyLibraryTargetTwo"]
    ),
  ],
  dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
  ],
  targets: [
    // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
    // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages this package depends on.
    .target(
      name: "MyLibrary",
      dependencies: ["MyLibraryTargetOne", "MyLibraryTargetTwo"]
    ),
    .target(
      name: "MyLibraryTargetOne",
      dependencies: ["MyLibraryCore"]
    ),
    .target(
      name: "MyLibraryTargetTwo",
      dependencies: ["MyLibraryCore"]
    ),
    .target(
      name: "MyLibraryCore",
      dependencies: []
    ), 
    .testTarget(
      name: "MyLibraryTest",
      dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]
    ),
  ]
)
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's something not supported?

Comment: At first glance it should compile. You may check if you have made `init` public - but I realise this would yield another error. Clearing the module cache?

Comment: all `init` are public and no luck clearing the module cache

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your issue, but failed - and this is actually a good thing, because it means there is an error that can be fixed ;)

I created a single Package project in Xcode which is a library product containing two other libraries. The file structure looks as shown below:

[image]

The Package.swift file:

```
// swift-tools-version:5.3
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyLibrary", targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
        .library(name: "LibraryA", targets: ["LibraryA"]),
        .library(name: "LibraryB", targets: ["LibraryB"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [],
    targets: [
        .target(name: "MyLibrary",dependencies: ["LibraryA", "LibraryB"]),
        .target(name: "LibraryA",dependencies: []),
        .target(name: "LibraryB",dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyLibraryTests",
            dependencies: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ]
)
```

And here the Swift file from MyLibrary:

```
import LibraryA
import LibraryB

public struct MyModel {
    public let a: LibraryA.MyModel
    public let b: LibraryB.MyModel

    public init(a: LibraryA.MyModel, b: LibraryB.MyModel) {
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    }
}
```

A LibraryA/B file:

```
public struct MyModel {
    public init() {}
}
```

The XCTest file:

```
import XCTest
import LibraryB
import LibraryA
import MyLibrary

final class MyLibraryTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        _ = MyModel(a: LibraryA.MyModel(), b: LibraryB.MyModel())
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and links as expected.

Comment: :( this is exactly with I did, but I'm still not able to compile, I'll try again in a fresh project. thx

Comment: I found the issue, in LibraryA/B target I have also a struct named LibraryA/B and the compiler isn't able to infer the "type"

Comment: @Batti Yes, this is actually a problem: when your module is named "Foo", and you have another enum, struct, class etc with the name "Foo" then there are situations where even in the same library qualified accesses cannot be resolved by the compiler. For example, when you have to disambiguate a free function `foo()` you would use `Foo.foo()` - where "Foo" is the module name - but then the compiler complains that struct "Foo" has no member "foo()".